# Error in parentNode.replaceChild

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     function filenameset() {

         var str1 = "...";
         document.getElementById("attachremove").style.visibility = "hidden";
         var filename = document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value;
         var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
         if (lastIndex >= 0) {
             filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
         }
         
         var FileExt = filename.split('.').pop();
         FileExt = FileExt.toUpperCase();
         if (FileExt == "EXE" || FileExt == "BAT" || FileExt == "CMD" || FileExt == "JSE" || FileExt == "MSI" || FileExt == "VB" || FileExt == "VBE" || FileExt == "VBS" || FileExt == "PS1") {
             document.getElementById("lblFileName").style.color = "Red"
             document.getElementById("lblFileName").innerHTML = "Files of this type cannot be attached";
             //document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value = '';
             var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
                 var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
                 return false;
             }
             else {
                 if (filename.length > 30) {
                     // filename1 = filename.substring(0, 20);
                     // filename2 = filename.substring(filename.length - 20, filename.length);
                     // filename = filename1.concat("...",filename2)
                     filename = filename.substring(filename.length - 30, filename.length);
                     filename = str1.concat(filename)
                  }
                  document.getElementById("lblFileName").innerHTML = filename;
                  document.getElementById("attachremove").style.visibility = "Visible";
              }
              //          mih cr s
             // document.getElementById("btnAttach2").style.visibility = "Visible";
              //document.getElementById("FileUpload2").style.visibility = "Visible";
              //          mih cr
          }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function filenameset2() {
         var str1 = "...";
         document.getElementById("imgAttchRemv2").style.visibility = "hidden";
         var filename = document.getElementById("FileUpload2").value;
         var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
         if (lastIndex >= 0) {
             filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
         }
         var FileExt = filename.split('.').pop();
         FileExt = FileExt.toUpperCase();
         if (FileExt == "EXE" || FileExt == "BAT" || FileExt == "CMD" || FileExt == "JSE" || FileExt == "MSI" || FileExt == "VB" || FileExt == "VBE" || FileExt == "VBS" || FileExt == "PS1") {
             //document.getElementById("lblFileName2").style.color = "Red"
             //document.getElementById("lblFileName2").innerHTML = "Files of this type cannot be attached";
             document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName2.ClientID %>').style.color = "Red"
             document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Files of this type cannot be attached";
             //document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value = '';
             var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload2");
             var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
             browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);
             return false;
        }
        else {
            if (filename.length > 30) {

                filename = filename.substring(filename.length - 30, filename.length);
                filename = str1.concat(filename)
            }
            //document.getElementById("lblFileName2").innerHTML = filename;
            document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = filename;
            document.getElementById("imgAttchRemv2").style.visibility = "Visible";
              }
             // document.getElementById("btnAttach3").style.visibility = "Visible";
             // document.getElementById("FileUpload3").style.visibility = "Visible";
          }
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
                function attachmentremove() {
                    var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
                    var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
                    browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);

                }
      </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          function attachmentremove2() {
              var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload2");
              
              var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
             browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);

          }
      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filenameset3() {

        var str1 = "...";
        document.getElementById("imgAttchRemv3").style.visibility = "hidden";
        var filename = document.getElementById("FileUpload3").value;
        var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
        if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
        }
        var FileExt = filename.split('.').pop();
        FileExt = FileExt.toUpperCase();
        if (FileExt == "EXE" || FileExt == "BAT" || FileExt == "CMD" || FileExt == "JSE" || FileExt == "MSI" || FileExt == "VB" || FileExt == "VBE" || FileExt == "VBS" || FileExt == "PS1") {
            //document.getElementById("lblFileName3").style.color = "Red"
            //document.getElementById("lblFileName3").innerHTML = "Files of this type cannot be attached";
            document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName3.ClientID %>').style.color = "Red"
            document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Files of this type cannot be attached";

            //document.getElementById("FileUpload1").value = '';
            var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload3");
            var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
            browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (filename.length > 30) {

                filename = filename.substring(filename.length - 30, filename.length);
                filename = str1.concat(filename)
            }
            // document.getElementById("lblFileName3").innerHTML = filename;
            document.getElementById('<%=lblFileName3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = filename;
            document.getElementById("imgAttchRemv3").style.visibility = "Visible";
        }
    }
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function attachmentremove3() {
              var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload3");
           
              var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
              browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);

          }
      </script>
```

```html
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table style="width: 430px; height: 37px;">
    <tr>
       <td class="style57">
                            
                    <label class="fileContainer">
                        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Attach" 
                            style="border: 1px solid #A29988; background-image:url(''); width:70px; height:20px; background-color:#E3E0DB; " />
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat ="server"
                            BorderStyle="None" style="width: 50px; top: 0px;" 
                            BackColor="#F0F0F0" onchange="return filenameset();" />
                     </label>
                     </td>
                             <td  style="margin-left:20px; width:220px;">         
                           <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat ="server" style="margin-left:4px; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; width:200px;"></asp:Label>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="attachremove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/attachremove.bmp" ToolTip="Remove attachment" Visible="true" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick ="attachmentremove();" style="margin-left:5px; position:absolute; padding-top:4px; visibility:hidden;"></asp:ImageButton>
                           </td> 
                     <td style="width:50px;">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" BorderColor="#A29988" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" style="margin-left: 0px; text-align:center" 
                            Text="Submit" BackColor="#E3E0DB" Height="20px" Width="54px" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                     </table>
                    <table style="width: 430px; height: 37px;">
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                    <label class="fileContainer">
                                            <input id="btnAttach2"  type="button" value="Attach" 
                            style="border: 1px solid #A29988; background-image:url(''); width:70px; height:20px; background-color:#E3E0DB;    " />


                        </label>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat ="server"
                            BorderStyle="None" style="width: 50px; top: 0px; " 
                            BackColor="#F0F0F0" onchange="return filenameset2(); " />
                    </td>
                    <td  style="margin-left:20px; width:220px;">         
                           <asp:Label ID="lblFilename2"  runat="server" style="margin-left:4px; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; width:200px;"></asp:Label>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAttchRemv2" runat="server"   ImageUrl="~/Images/attachremove.bmp" ToolTip="Remove attachment" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick ="attachmentremove2();" style="margin-left:5px; position:absolute; padding-top:4px; "></asp:ImageButton>
                           </td> 
                    </tr>
                     </table>
                    <table style="width: 430px; height: 37px;">
                     <tr>
                    <td>
                    <label class="fileContainer">
                        <input id="btnAttach3"   type="button" value="Attach" 
                            style="border: 1px solid #A29988; background-image:url(''); width:70px; height:20px; background-color:#E3E0DB; " />
                        </label>

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat ="server"
                            BorderStyle="None" style="width: 50px; top: 0px; " 
                            BackColor="#F0F0F0" onchange="return filenameset3();" />
                    </td>
                    <td  style="margin-left:20px; width:220px;">         
                           <asp:Label ID="lblFilename3" runat="server" style="margin-left:4px; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; width:200px;"></asp:Label>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAttchRemv3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/attachremove.bmp" ToolTip="Remove attachment"  CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick ="attachmentremove3();" style="margin-left:5px; position:absolute; padding-top:4px; "></asp:ImageButton>
                           </td> 
                    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I am developing a web upload page in asp.net. Here I am providing interface to select different files as shown in fig.

[image]

It works properly. Here I have provided option to remove wrong file selections before uploading. But if I click on second or 3rd button all the selected images(1,2,3) gets deleted from page instead of respective selection.

This is the function I have given to button click,

```
function attachmentremove()
         {
             var browse = document.getElementById("FileUpload");
             var newbrowse = browse.cloneNode(false);
             browse.parentNode.replaceChild(newbrowse, browse);

          }
```

I have given 3 different functions for different button click.

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Can you show the HTML and the other two functions?

Comment: @Arg0n added the code to question. Can please you find errors in it ?

Comment: The `id` on the client will not be the same as in ASP.NET, you have to use e.g. `<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>`.

Comment: @Arg0n Still I am getting same error. I need to change id only in attachremovement functions right ?

Comment: Everywhere you use them, or store them in `variables`.

Comment: @Arg0n still same error. Is there any other possibilities for this error ?

Comment: Yes of course, error in the coding.

Comment: @Arg0n Can you please try to solve this error ?

Comment: Do you have this code running somewhere for me to test?  I'm having trouble following what the problem is and what's causing it.